# How to remove a small 2 second portion of audio from an mpeg video file in Mac?

Tags: video-editor, audio, mac, imovie

I currently have a 1 minute long video where in the beginning of the video someone says something inappropriate. I was wondering what the easiest way to silence that part of the video would be. I am wondering if Quicktime or iMovie can do the job in Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg (terminal tool).
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/wiki/Installing-ffmpeg-on-Mac-OS-X

Copy the audio into a separate file.
Then use ffmpeg again to silence desired part (https://stackoverflow.com/q/38180809/2792138 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/29215197/2792138).

Then merge new audio file with the initial video file, replacing old audio track.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a Non Linear editing tool such as the one you mentioned (iMovie) to achieve this, as you'd need the ability to separate your audio from video.

See [How to separate audio from a video track in iMovie](https://wmsnewmacs.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/how-to-separate-audio-from-a-video-track-in-imovie/) to guide you using iMovie.